# Does it make sense to say: "One time I spent everyday ...?"

Tags: phrase-usage

Example sentence:

> One time I spent everyday sending letters, pretending to be somebody I
>   wasn't.

My logics is this: one time means only *once*, but by adding *everyday* I'm saying that it happened *more than once*. So the phrase contradicts itself.

But maybe a week or a month can also be considered "one time"?

I'm not sure if I'm wrong, though. If I am, what's a more appropriate word choice?

Comment: It does sound odd. How about starting the sentence with "For a while ..." instead?

Comment: @SteveLovell For a while I spent everyday ...? Does that sound natural?

Comment: (A while ago / back) I **once** spent the time pretending to be someone else and I **would** send letters...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the suggestion. I think "A while back" would be suitable too?

Comment: Perhaps ***At one time...*** would convey what you want.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers.  His example is precisely what I would have suggested.  Also, he is exactly correct about *every day* versus *everyday*.  *Every day I eat toast* versus *Eating toast is an everyday activity for me*.  (This is happening with a lot of other words in English too, e.g. *set up* versus *setup*, *back yard* versus *backyard*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *[once](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/once)* and *one time* can be used to mean *formerly* and refer to an extended time in the past (seen as a single span of time). The *OED* offers more than one example,  including the following:

> He used to read one time. Doesn't he now?

(1971, *Whistle in the Dark* by T. Murphy)

> There used to be a public-house there one time...

(1888,  *W. Somerset Word-bk* by F. T. Elworthy)

In these uses, *one time* means *formerly* and not *on a single occasion*.

So, *one time* can indeed mean "a week or a month" (to quote your question)–just as *once* can.

> Once/one time, I spent every day sending letters, pretending to be somebody I wasn't.

So yes you can use *one time*. However, such words as *once* and *formerly* are used more often in today's English (these examples  with *one time* might seem a little odd to today's native  reader).

As for the date of *A Whistle in the Dark*, the *OED* lists the usage as from 1971, a date confirmed by the [World Catalog](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3Awhistle+in+dark+au%3Amurphy&fq=yr%3A1971..1971+%3E&qt=advanced&dblist=638); this work does not have to be in exact accordance with the script of the play apparently performed ten years earlier, and in any case, 1961 is still contemporary English and indeed [Drama Online](http://www.dramaonlinelibrary.com/series/contemporary-dramatists-iid-13282?sortField=dc_title_sortable&sortDirection=desc) considers Thomas Murphy a "contemporary dramatist."

Comment: Murphy actually wrote *Whistle in the Dark* in 1961, not '71. But imho your cited usage was no more "natural" to mainstream Anglophones then than it is now. Perhaps it survived as a dialectal Irish usage, or perhaps there was supposed to be a "subvocal" ***at*** there, I dunno. But I do note that just earlier in the same utterance, the speaker (*Dada*, an older person?) said ***I'm reading** that now, just before **I came** over.* Again, that might be / have been dialectically credible, but it's certainly not "standard English".